# JAXWS Client ServiceConfigurationError on weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic, jax-ws, webclient, wsimport

I have created a client to connect to external webservice. This was done by using wsimport to generate the artifacts and then copied the java classes in my existing web application.
I have tomcat on my workstation and this projects deploys and functions perfectly in this environment.
But as soon as I deploy the same to weblogic servers I get the below error.
Can you please help me understand the problem and its potential solution.

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider: Provider weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider could not be instantiated: java.lang.ClassCastException 
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:207) 
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:164) 
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:353) 
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:421) 
at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.getProviderUsingServiceLoader(Provider.java:180) 
at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:140) 
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:92)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's highly likely that the `WLSProvider` class was found in two jar files on your classpath. You will need to check your classpath for duplicates

Comment: The issue occurred becaue of difference in JVM versions on my local and server. The artifacts generated on local system was running JDK 1.7 and the server was running JDK 1.6. After generating the artifacts on 1.6 , the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In my case importing jaxb - api did the trick

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>...</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the version of jaxws-api.jar library and it worked. I was using 2.2.5 and I changed it to 2.1-1 version and it worked for me.

Also, in the META-INF/weblogic-application.xml of your EAR, put

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <weblogic-application xmlns="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/90">
<application-param>
    <param-name>webapp.encoding.default</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
</application-param>
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.jws.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.wsdl.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.ctc.wstx.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.xml.ws.*</package-name>
    <package-name>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```